# Why transpose data to get a multiindexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm a bit confused with data orientation when creating a Multiindexed DataFrame from a DataFrame.
I import data with `read_excel()` and I begin with something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
columns=['k', 'k', 'm', 'm'])
df

Out[3]: 
   k  k  m  m
0  A  B  A  B
1  1  2  3  4
```

I want to multiindex this and to obtain:

```py
   A  B  A  B
   k  k  m  m
0  1  2  3  4
```

Mainly from Pandas' doc, I did:

```py
arrays = df.iloc[0].tolist(), list(df)
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['topLevel', 'downLevel'])
df = df.drop(0)
```

If I try

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values, index=multiindex)
(...)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 4)
```

I then have to transpose the values:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, index=multiindex)
df2
Out[11]: 
                    0
topLevel downLevel   
A        k          1
B        k          2
A        m          3
B        m          4
```

Last I re-transpose this dataframe to obtain:

```py
df2.T
Out[12]: 
topLevel   A  B  A  B
downLevel  k  k  m  m
0          1  2  3  4
```

OK, this is what I want, but I don't understand why I have to transpose 2 times. It seems useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `MultiIndex` yourself, and then drop the row. From your starting `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0], df.columns], names=[None]*2)
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

   A  B  A  B
   k  k  m  m
0  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: OK. I definitively go back to Pandas doc on indexing.